# Bootstrap classes not being applied on modal window elements

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a bootstrap modal form window. The window appears on desired click but the no styles(classes) appear on them. I mean the whole design is disturbed with no colors and no alignments. Can anyone let me know what can be improved? I am posting my code here for modal window. I am not sure if I am leaving something vital,I have already spent some 2-3 hours on this and still clueless.

```
 <style>
    .modal-notify .modal-header {
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}
.modal-notify .modal-content {
    border-radius: 3px;

}
 </style>

<div class="modal fade" id="orangeModalSubscription" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-notify modal-warning" role="document">
    <!--Content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <!--Header-->
      <div class="modal-header text-center">
        <h4 class="modal-title white-text w-100 font-weight-bold py-2">Subscribe</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true" class="white-text">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <!--Body-->
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="md-form mb-5">
          <i class="fas fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
          <input type="text" id="form3" class="form-control validate">
          <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="form3">Name</label>
        </div>

        <div class="md-form">
          <i class="fas fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
          <input type="email" id="form2" class="form-control validate">
          <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="form2">Email</label>
        </div>

         <div class="md-form">
          <i class="fas fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
          <input type="mobile" id="form2" class="form-control validate">
          <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="form2">Mobile</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--Footer-->
      <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning waves-effect">Send <i class="fas fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/.Content-->
  </div>
</div>`
```

Comment: try ading a transparent border,
 OR,
set overflow to hidden. 
Else we need a working code snippet in codenpen or here.

Answer (score 0):

have you included bootstrap css in the page ?

Comment: Yes I have.  `<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: are the bootstrap resources loaded on your network log browser ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include bootstrap in you HTML page, inside your `<head></head>` tag:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Comment: Using this link completely disturbs my design for the page. All my menu items get deformed and out of design. Something else can be done?

Comment: Can you paste here what are you "importing" in your head tag ?? @Ansh

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }        
        .modal-notify .modal-header {
            border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
        }        
        .modal-notify .modal-content {
            border-radius: 3px;
        }
        .fade:not(.show) {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        .modal {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1050;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            outline: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="modal fade" id="orangeModalSubscription" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-notify modal-warning" role="document">
            <!--Content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <!--Header-->
                <div class="modal-header text-center">
                    <h4 class="modal-title white-text w-100 font-weight-bold py-2">Subscribe</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true" class="white-text">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <!--Body-->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="md-form mb-5">
                        <i class="fas fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
                        <input type="text" id="form3" class="form-control validate">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="form3">Name</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form">
                        <i class="fas fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
                        <input type="email" id="form2" class="form-control validate">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="form2">Email</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form">
                        <i class="fas fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
                        <input type="mobile" id="form2" class="form-control validate">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="form2">Mobile</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--Footer-->
                <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
                    <a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning waves-effect">Send <i class="fas fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--/.Content-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this Piyush. Its showing up. But the issue coming now here is the modal form is not visible on mobile view. The form does not pops up at all. Can something be done for that?